# Jest Mock Class - Implementation as imported module

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a contructor of a class from an imported module. It works if my mock implementation is inlined into the jest.mock() factory function, but not if the implementation is imported from another file.

**This works:**

**`test.ts:`**

```
jest.mock('external-lib', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@external-lib');

  function ClassMock(): any {
    return {
      method1: (val: number): Promise<any> => {
        return Promise.resolve({ a: val });
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    StrategyComputation: jest.fn(ClassMock),
  };
});
```

**This does not work**

If I take the function `ClassMock` out into another file `mocks.ts` and import it in the test file, it does not work:

**`test.ts:`**

```
import { ClassMock } from './mocks'; 

jest.mock('external-lib', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@external-lib');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    StrategyComputation: jest.fn(ClassMock),
  };
});
```

**`mocks.ts:`**

```
  export function ClassMock(): any {
    return {
      method1: (val: number): Promise<any> => {
        return Promise.resolve({ a: val });
      },
    };
  }
```

If fails with a

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ClassMock' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to keep the `function() {}` inside the mock factory, and import the class methods implementations only:

**`test.ts:`**

```
import { MockFunctions } from './mocks'; 

jest.mock('external-lib', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@external-lib');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    StrategyComputation: jest.fn(function() {
        return MockFunctions
    }),
  };
});
```

**`mocks.ts:`**

```
  export const MockFunctions = {
    method1: (val: number): Promise<any> => {
      return Promise.resolve({ a: val });
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for mock.  It's a lot easier.

```
import Axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

describe('MyClass', () => {
  it('test doSomething', async () => {
    const axios = Axios as jest.Mocked<typeof Axios>;
    axios.request.mockResolvedValue({});

    const result = new MyClass().doSomething();

    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: The question is how to write the mock implementation into another file and import it. In your case your mock is simple, returns {}. In my case it is very complex and I want to have it in another file.

Comment: You can use the fixture in your other file to return the desired output.  `axios.request.mockResolveValue(MyTestFixture.getComplexSuccessResponse())`.  This is what I typically have seen in many orgs.  Otherwise, you're mocking the module and have to match method signatures which can become a pain at times, esp if you use Typescript.